# Loop within Swift Eureka Form

Tags: ios, swift3, eureka-forms

I am building a Eureka form and would like to put a loop within the form to build a list of steppers based on an array.

The code I am trying to use is:

```
let itemNames = ["one","two","three"]

// Eureka From Set-up
form
    +++ Section("Select item values")

    for itemName in itemNames{
        <<< StepperRow() {
            $0.tag = itemName
            $0.title = itemName
            $0.value = 0
        }
    }
```

However, when I do this I get an error on the StepperRow line that says:

```
Unary operator cannot be separated from its operand
```

So it looks as though Swift no longer thinks it is within the form and is looking at the < symbol as less than, rather than the row declaration.

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: I guess the lines to build the form are required be in / on the same scope / level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<<<` is a binary operator, which expects two operands (`lhs <<< rhs`), whereas in your example above, you only supply it one (`<<< operand`).

It's not possible to "pipe" each pass of a `for` loop such as if each pass was a `rhs` to be used with a `lhs` operand outside of the scope of the loop (with `lhs` for first pass being the result of `form +++ Section(...)`). You could, however, make use of `reduce` to achieve such functionality. Now, I haven't tested this with Eureka forms (however on dummy structures and operators), but it should look something like the following: (based on the `+++` and `<<<` operator functions declared in [Eureka/Source/Core/Operators.swift](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Source/Core/Operators.swift))

```
form 
    +++ itemNames.reduce(Section("Select item values")) { (section, itemName) in
        section 
            <<< StepperRow() {
                $0.tag = itemName
                $0.title = itemName
                $0.value = 0
            }
    }
```

Comment: I understand that. <<< is a specific syntax for Eureka forms and so when not within a For loop works correctly. My question is mote about Eureka and putting a loop within a Eureka Form. The space is required as part of that Syntax

Comment: @MichaelMoulsdale updated my answer (untested for Eureka framework, but tested on dummy types and operators).

Comment: Awesome, was really sceptical of the answer but it worked a treat. @xmartlabs, you guys should really add this to the documentation

Comment: @MichaelMoulsdale good to hear that it worked also in practice with Eureka. Happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

Alternative answer:

```
let itemNames = ["one","two","three"]

// Eureka From Set-up
form
    +++ Section("Select item values")

    for itemName in itemNames{

    form.last

        <<< StepperRow() {
            $0.tag = itemName
            $0.title = itemName
            $0.value = 0
        }
    }
```

You just have to add "form.last" inside the for.loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
  //You can use following approach :-

    let itemNames = ["one","two","three"]
    let section = Section("Select item values")
    form +++ section
    // Eureka From Set-up
    for itemName in itemNames{
        section <<< StepperRow() {
            $0.tag = itemName
            $0.title = itemName
            $0.value = 0
        }
    }
```